# linq2db .NET ORM partial updates?

Tags: orm, linq2db

We use Linq2DB ORM library for our .NET ORM models
see https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db

How to send update with only changed columns?
Now the SQL query includes all of the columns and values

Answer (score 8):

Currently there is no mechanism for tracking changes in the object level to update only the changed properties but if you know what columns are changed, you can use the set function in conjunction with the update function to do the partial updates (just like the example given in the github page )

```
using (var db = new DbNorthwind())
{
   db.Product
    .Where(p => p.ProductID == product.ProductID)
    .Set(p => p.Name, product.Name)
   .Set(p => p.UnitPrice, product.UnitPrice)
  .Update();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, linq2db is a lightweight ORM. What means it doesn't have heavy context and it doesn't know anything about changes in entities and never will-if you want to have change tracking than use Entity Framework or NHibernate. So you have to implement change tracking yourself (if you really need it) or update the whole entity(like you did). If you know updated column you can use any syntax provided (see [Linq2Db crud operations](http://blog.linq2db.com/2015/05/linq-crud-operations.html)). If you know only changed column names-you can dynamically construct linq expressions and use one of syntaxes [Linq2Db crud operations](http://blog.linq2db.com/2015/05/linq-crud-operations.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement for L2DB and I ended up writing this code below.  It uses a wrapper class (`BaseAuditor`), but hopefully you get the idea.  One day, I *might* move this code into some kind of base POCO class which all my L2DB classes in turn inherit from, but in truth I'm not sure that the performance hit will be worth it.  Anyway, for what it's worth:

```
        private class Change
        {
            public MemberExpression Extract = null;
            public object Value = null;

        }

        private List<Change> Changes = new List<Change>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Records this change, for application later
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TV"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="extract"></param>
        /// <param name="value"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public BaseAuditor<T> Set<TV>(Expression<Func<T, TV>> extract, TV value)
        {
            // Record this change for use later

            var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)extract.Body;
            this.Changes.Add(new Change() {Extract = memberExpression, Value = value});

            return this;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Applies our changes to the given entity
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entity"></param>
        private void ApplyChanges(T entity)
        {
            foreach (var change in this.Changes) {
                var property = (PropertyInfo)change.Extract.Member;
                property.SetValue(entity, change.Value, null);
            }
        }
```